# How to set to redux store following ajax call?

Tags: ajax, redux, redux-thunk

Not sure what I'm missing here. The `console.log` prints the correct `data`, but the `return` statement is not setting the values to my redux store.

// reducer.js

```
function getPreviousMonthData(state) {
  $.ajax({
    url: uri,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: (data) => {
      const newObj = {
        previousMonthTotal: data.totals[0],
        previousMonth: data.app_reports
      };
      console.log(newObj);
      return Object.assign({}, state, newObj);
    }
  });
}
```

In every other context of my app, `return Object.assign({}, state, newObj);` successfully sets data to my redux store, e.g.:

// reducer.js

```
function setState(state, newState) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, newState);
}

function setToStore(state, data, label) {
  let newObj = {};
  newObj[label] = data;
  return Object.assign({}, state, newObj);
}
```

EDIT: this is the `reducer` side of the action... my `action-creator` is a little bit wacky. The fuller story is that this ajax call comes at the end of a chain of dispatched actions that began with a different ajax call. The overall goal is to (1) receive one set of data based upon a range given by two unix time stamps; (2) calculate the prior month's range; and (3) take that new date range to create a new get request for the prior month's data. Everything works except for the final assignment of the prior month's data to the redux store.

// action_creators.js

```
export function getDataPointQuery(queryObj) {
  const app = queryObj.app_id ? queryObj.app_id : CONFIG.test_app;
  const token = queryObj.token ? queryObj.token : CONFIG.token;
  const start_date = queryObj.start_date ? queryObj.start_date : CONFIG.start_date;
  const end_date = queryObj.end_date ? queryObj.end_date : CONFIG.end_date;
  const uri = CONFIG.host2+"/v3/apps/"+app+"/app_reports?token="+token+"&start="+queryObj.start_date+"&end="+queryObj.end_date;

  return(dispatch) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: uri,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
    }).then((data) => {
      dispatch(setToStore(app, "appId"));
      dispatch(setToStore(token, "token"));
      dispatch(setToStore(data.app_reports, "dataQueryPeriod"));
      dispatch(setToStore(data.totals[0], "dataQueryPeriodTotal"));
      dispatch(setToStore(data.app_reports[0].created_at, "startDate"));
      dispatch(setToStore(data.app_reports[data.app_reports.length-1].created_at, "endDate"));
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch(getPreviousMonthDates());
      dispatch(createChartJsData());
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch(getPreviousMonthData());
    });
  };
}
```

Essentially, the final dispatch is failing to work as anticipated. I'm also cognizant of the fact that it is extraordinarily inelegant to make one ajax call from `action_creators` and another ajax call from `reducer`. I was hoping to get it working once and then refactor.

Comment: Why you don't use reducers and dispatching actions.

Comment: The reducer sould be a pure function. That means no API calls or other _side effects_. You should refactor the ajax data fetch logic to `actions`. After the data is recieved, dispatch the action.

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice from guruPitka, I ditched the `reducer` ajax call and implemented it into the `action_creator`, which created the following behemoth:

```
export function getDataPointQuery(queryObj) {
  // variables and stuff

  return(dispatch) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: uri,
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json"
    }).then((data) => {
      dispatch(setToStore(app, "appId"));
      dispatch(setToStore(token, "token"));
      dispatch(setToStore(data.app_reports, "dataQueryPeriod"));
      dispatch(setToStore(data.totals[0], "dataQueryPeriodTotal"));
      dispatch(getMonthDates());
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch(getPreviousMonthDates());
      dispatch(createChartJsData());
    }).then(() => {    
      $.ajax({
        url: previousUri,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
      }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        dispatch(setToStore(result.app_reports, "previousMonth"));
        dispatch(setToStore(result.totals[0], "previousMonthTotal"));
      });
    });
  };
}
```